# Visual Studio 2019 Missing SQL CLR VB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools, sqlclr

In VS2019 under "Project | Add New Item | Installed | SQL Server" I have the "SLQ CLR C#" option but not the "SQL CLR VB" option. How do I get the VB option?

The SQL Server 2019 documentation has both C# and VB examples (e.g. [CLR User-Defined Aggregate - Invoking Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-aggregate-invoking-functions?view=sql-server-ver15)). I have VB.Net setup in VS2019.  However, the SQL CLR VB option is not available.

Have I missed a component in the install or do I have to download something from the VS Marketplace?

Comment: Add New Item normally shows "Visual C#" or "Visual Basic" under Installed Templates depending on the current project type. Are you trying to add an item to an existing VB.net project? Or is it a C# project?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I created a new SQL Server Database project. It didn't notice a language selection option.

Comment: @Edmund, is this still an issue? It's been a while since I installed VS, but perhaps it was an option for which languages to install support for? As in: C#, VB.NET, and Visual C++. But, I could be misremembering.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Yes. This is still unresolved. I didn't notice any options in the install wizard. Do you know of any from the command line?

Comment: Ok. Under "project properties", in the "SQLCLR" tab (I think) there should be a drop-down for "Language" where you can select either C# or VB.NET. I assume yours is set to C#? If so, try changing to VB.NET and then go back to Add New Item and see if it now shows "SQL CLR VB" instead of "SQL CLR C#".

Comment: @SolomonRutzky That is it.  Many thanks.  Add an answer and I will accept. Project | <Name> Properties | SQLCLR | Language. The dropdown is greyed as if it cannot be selected but you can select and change the language.  Then Project | Add New Item | SQL Server | SQL CLR VB will show instead of C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should have to do with the language set for the (database) project itself. Try the following steps:

1. Go to the "Project" menu
2. Select "<Project_Name> Properties"
3. Go to the "SQLCLR" tab
4. There should be a dropdown for "Language".

   The dropdown is greyed as if it cannot be selected, but you can select it and change the language to "VB"

After making that change:

1. Go to "Add New Item" (either via the "Project" menu or by right-clicking the project in Object Explorer)
2. Select "SQL Server"

   "SQL CLR VB" should show instead of "SQL CLR C#".